# How to change rootViewController in swift?

Tags: swift, uinavigationcontroller

I am working on an application in which there is no login logout feature. When user opens the application he sees main screen. Now there is an option in setting page named as Pin Lock application. When user select this option a PinScreen comes(like OTP Screen) then user sets the Pin. After that When user closes the application the Pin lock screen comes first asking user to enter pin.
So how can i do that?

```
if UserDefaults.standard.bool(forKey: "LoggedIn") == false {

        let story = UIStoryboard(name: "Main", bundle:nil)
        let vc = story.instantiateViewController(withIdentifier: "EnterPin") as! UINavigationController
        UIApplication.shared.windows.first?.rootViewController = vc
        UIApplication.shared.windows.first?.makeKeyAndVisible()

        let enterPinViewController = self.storyboard.instantiateViewController(identifier: "EnterPinViewController") as! EnterPinViewController
        self.navigationController.present(enterPinViewController, animated: true, completion: nil)

    } else if UserDefaults.standard.bool(forKey: "LoggedIn") == true {

        let story = UIStoryboard(name: "Main", bundle:nil)
        let vc = story.instantiateViewController(withIdentifier: "MainController") as! UINavigationController
        UIApplication.shared.windows.first?.rootViewController = vc
        UIApplication.shared.windows.first?.makeKeyAndVisible()

        let mainViewController = self.storyboard.instantiateViewController(identifier: "ViewController") as! ViewController
        self.navigationController.present(mainViewController, animated: true, completion: nil)


    }
```

Currently i am setting UserDefaults value as true and false and saving Pin in UserDefaults itself. I have tried changing rootViewController but nothing happening means every time main screen is coming instead of Pin Screen.

Comment: What does whether or not you turn on the option have to do the rootViewController?

Comment: "I have tried changing rootViewController but nothing happening"  Where?  Nobody sees a single line of code.

Comment: Hey El i have updated my question with code. And I said rootViewController because i thought i have to change it?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

First you need to get the **Window** from **SceneDelegate** and use that window for **rootViewController**.

**Suggestion**: Whenever we are using **rootViewController** then no need to do **present** and **push** thing it will automatically **set as a main home viewcontroller(Intial viewController)**

```
 let window = (UIApplication.shared.connectedScenes.first!.delegate as! SceneDelegate).window
            let storyboard = UIStoryboard(name: "Main", bundle:nil)
        if UserDefaults.standard.bool(forKey: "LoggedIn") == false {
            let vc =storyboard.instantiateViewController(withIdentifier: "EnterPin") as! UINavigationController
            window?.rootViewController = vc
            window?.makeKeyAndVisible()
        } else if UserDefaults.standard.bool(forKey: "LoggedIn") == true {
            let vc =storyboard.instantiateViewController(withIdentifier: "MainController") as! UINavigationController
            window?.rootViewController = vc
            window?.makeKeyAndVisible()
        }
```

I **suggest** you do all this things in SceneDelegate file

```
func scene(_ scene: UIScene, willConnectTo session: UISceneSession, options connectionOptions: UIScene.ConnectionOptions) {
        guard let scene = (scene as? UIWindowScene) else { return }
        self.window = UIWindow(windowScene: scene)
        let storyboard = UIStoryboard(name: "Main", bundle: nil)
        if UserDefaults.standard.bool(forKey: "LoggedIn") == false {
            let vc = storyboard.instantiateViewController(withIdentifier: "EnterPin") as! UINavigationController
            self.window?.rootViewController = vc
            self.window?.makeKeyAndVisible()
        } else if UserDefaults.standard.bool(forKey: "LoggedIn") == true {
            let vc = storyboard.instantiateViewController(withIdentifier: "MainController") as! UINavigationController
            self.window?.rootViewController = vc
            self.window?.makeKeyAndVisible()
        }
    }
```

I Hope it is helpful for you!

Comment: Hi Yogesh thanks for the answer, i was doing this in AppDelegate.
But Problem is when i am installing app for first time it is showing me Pin Screen, which should not happen because AppPin has not yet set by user. So how can it be resolved?

Comment: assign storyboard ID too your viewcontrollers not your navigationcontroller.

Comment: Thanks for your answer. :) I solved this by registering userDefault value.

Comment: Please have a look at this https://stackoverflow.com/questions/77137171/uicollectionviewcells-are-hiding-while-scrolling

Answer (score 1):

```
let viewController = MainViewController()

guard let appDelegate = UIApplication.shared.delegate as? AppDelegate else {
   return
 }
    
guard let window = appDelegate.window else {
   return
}
    
window.rootViewController = viewController
```

Comment: How can i use it? Can you please tell me?