# UICollectionViewCells are disappearing while scrolling

Tags: swift, uicollectionview, uicollectionviewcell

I am implementing a UICollectionView in in which there are 20 to 1000 counts. In this collectionview, i have a label and a view in cell. For every multiple of 5 the view of cell is bigger as compared to normal non-multiplied of 5 view.
The issue here i'm facing is that, when i am running the code in the simulator and scrolling left or right it is working fine. But when i am using the iOS physical device, installing application using "installonair.com" or "diawi.com" the collection view is hiding(not visible) when i am scrolling the collectionview(it is visible when i tap on it but again if i scroll it is hiding again). Scroll direction of UICollectionView is Horizontal.

I have done the following code to get this work.

```
class UserWeightViewController: UIViewController {
    
    @IBOutlet var weightCollectionView: UICollectionView!
    var userWeightType : String = "kg"
    var newWeightArray = [20,21,22,23,24,25,26,27,28,29,30,31,32,33,34,35,36,37,38,39,40,41,42,43,44,45,46,47,48,49,50,51,52,53,54,55,56,57,58,59,60]
    
    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()
        // Do any additional setup after loading the view.
        weightCollectionView.backgroundColor = .clear
        weightCollectionView.register(UICollectionReusableView.self, forSupplementaryViewOfKind: UICollectionView.elementKindSectionHeader, withReuseIdentifier: "collectionHeaderview")
        weightCollectionView.register(UICollectionReusableView.self, forSupplementaryViewOfKind: UICollectionView.elementKindSectionFooter, withReuseIdentifier: "collectionFooter")
        
        for i in 0..<25 {
            self.loadMoreData()
        }
    }
    
    
    override func viewDidLayoutSubviews() {
        weightCollectionView.scrollToItem(at: IndexPath(item: 40, section: 0), at: .centeredHorizontally, animated: false)
    }
    
    func loadMoreData() {
        for _ in 1..<55 {
            let lastItem = newWeightArray.last!
            let newNumbers = lastItem + 1
            newWeightArray.append(newNumbers)
        }
        weightCollectionView.reloadData()
    }
    
}


extension UserWeightViewController: UICollectionViewDelegate, UICollectionViewDataSource, UICollectionViewDelegateFlowLayout {
    
    func numberOfSections(in collectionView: UICollectionView) -> Int {
        return 1
    }
    
    func collectionView(_ collectionView: UICollectionView, numberOfItemsInSection section: Int) -> Int {
        return newWeightArray.count
        
    }
    
    func collectionView(_ collectionView: UICollectionView, cellForItemAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> UICollectionViewCell {
        let cell = collectionView.dequeueReusableCell(withReuseIdentifier: "WeightCollectionViewCell", for: indexPath) as! WeightCollectionViewCell
        
        cell.name = "\(newWeightArray[indexPath.row])"
        
        if (indexPath.row % 5 == 0)
        {
            cell.cellLineView.backgroundColor = UIColor(red: 94/255, green: 93/255, blue: 152/255, alpha: 1.0)
            cell.cellWeightLabel.isHidden = false
            //            cell.kgLabel.isHidden = false
            cell.cellLineViewHeightConstraint.constant = 35
        } else {
            cell.cellLineView.backgroundColor = UIColor(red: 94/255, green: 93/255, blue: 152/255, alpha: 0.8)
            cell.cellWeightLabel.isHidden = true
            cell.kgLabel.isHidden = true
            
            cell.cellLineViewHeightConstraint.constant = 20
        }
        
        let center = self.view.convert(collectionView.center, to: collectionView)
        let index = collectionView.indexPathForItem(at: center)
        if (indexPath == index) {
            cell.cellLineViewHeightConstraint.constant = 65
            cell.cellLineView.backgroundColor = UIColor(red: 97/255, green: 97/255, blue: 152/255, alpha: 1.0)
            cell.cellWeightLabel.font = UIFont.systemFont(ofSize: 34.0, weight: UIFont.Weight.heavy)
            cell.kgLabel.isHidden = false
            
            cell.cellWeightLabel.isHidden = false
        } else if (indexPath.row % 5 == 0) {
            cell.cellLineView.backgroundColor = UIColor(red: 94/255, green: 93/255, blue: 152/255, alpha: 1.0)
            cell.cellWeightLabel.isHidden = false
            cell.kgLabel.isHidden = false
            
            cell.cellLineViewHeightConstraint.constant = 35
            cell.cellLineView.backgroundColor = UIColor(red: 97/255, green: 97/255, blue: 152/255, alpha: 1.0)
            cell.cellWeightLabel.font = UIFont.systemFont(ofSize: 18.0, weight: UIFont.Weight.bold)
            cell.kgLabel.isHidden = true
        }else {
            cell.cellLineViewHeightConstraint.constant = 20
            cell.cellLineView.backgroundColor = UIColor(red: 152/255, green: 146/255, blue: 193/255, alpha: 1.0)
            cell.kgLabel.isHidden = true
        }
        if cell.cellWeightLabel.isHidden == true {
            cell.kgLabel.isHidden = true
        }
        
        if cell.cellWeightLabel.text == "20" || cell.cellWeightLabel.text == "21" || cell.cellWeightLabel.text == "22" || cell.cellWeightLabel.text == "23" || cell.cellWeightLabel.text == "1022" || cell.cellWeightLabel.text == "1023" || cell.cellWeightLabel.text == "1024" || cell.cellWeightLabel.text == "1025" {
            cell.cellWeightLabel.isHidden = true
            cell.kgLabel.isHidden = true
        }
        
        return cell
    }
    
    func collectionView(_ collectionView: UICollectionView, didSelectItemAt indexPath: IndexPath) {
        let selectedIndex = collectionView.indexPathsForSelectedItems?.first
        if collectionView == weightCollectionView {
            collectionView.scrollToItem(at: IndexPath(item: selectedIndex![1], section: 0), at: .centeredHorizontally, animated: true)
            let cell = collectionView.cellForItem(at: indexPath) as? WeightCollectionViewCell
            print("cell weight is ==>>",cell?.cellWeightLabel.text)
        }
    }
    
    func scrollViewDidScroll(_ scrollView: UIScrollView) {
        weightCollectionView.reloadData()
    }
    
    func collectionView(_ collectionView: UICollectionView, layout collectionViewLayout: UICollectionViewLayout, minimumLineSpacingForSectionAt section: Int) -> CGFloat {
        return 5
    }
    
    func collectionView(_ collectionView: UICollectionView, layout collectionViewLayout: UICollectionViewLayout, minimumInteritemSpacingForSectionAt section: Int) -> CGFloat {
        return 1
    }
    
    func collectionView(_ collectionView: UICollectionView, viewForSupplementaryElementOfKind kind: String, at indexPath: IndexPath) -> UICollectionReusableView {
        switch kind {
        case UICollectionView.elementKindSectionHeader:
            let headerView = collectionView.dequeueReusableSupplementaryView(ofKind: kind, withReuseIdentifier: "collectionHeaderview", for: indexPath)
            headerView.backgroundColor = UIColor(red: 240/255, green: 239/255, blue: 239/255, alpha: 1.0)
            return headerView
        case UICollectionView.elementKindSectionFooter:
            let footerView = collectionView.dequeueReusableSupplementaryView(ofKind: kind, withReuseIdentifier: "collectionFooter", for: indexPath)
            footerView.backgroundColor = UIColor(red: 240/255, green: 239/255, blue: 239/255, alpha: 1.0)
            return footerView
        default:
            assert(false, "Unexpected element kind")
        }
        fatalError("Unexpected element kind")
    }
    
    func collectionView(_ collectionView: UICollectionView, layout collectionViewLayout: UICollectionViewLayout, sizeForItemAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> CGSize {
        return  CGSize(width: 12, height: 120)
    }
    
    func collectionView(_ collectionView: UICollectionView, layout collectionViewLayout: UICollectionViewLayout, referenceSizeForHeaderInSection section: Int) -> CGSize {
        return CGSize(width: (self.weightCollectionView.frame.width/2)+15, height: 1)
    }
    
    func collectionView(_ collectionView: UICollectionView, layout collectionViewLayout: UICollectionViewLayout, referenceSizeForFooterInSection section: Int) -> CGSize {
        return CGSize(width: self.weightCollectionView.frame.width/2, height: view.frame.size.height)
    }
}


class WeightCollectionViewCell: UICollectionViewCell {
    
    @IBOutlet var cellWeightLabel: UILabel!
    @IBOutlet var kgLabel: UILabel!
    @IBOutlet var cellLineView: UIView!
    @IBOutlet var cellLineViewHeightConstraint: NSLayoutConstraint!
    
    
    var name : String? {
            didSet{
                self.updateUI()
            }
        }
    
    func updateUI() {
        cellWeightLabel.text = name
    }
    
}
```

While scrolling CollectionView is hiding.
Please let me know what i'm doing wrong here.